# How to copy output of command line from remote, to local clipboard via ssh

Tags: linux, bash, xclip

I am using HPC on campus and it is CentOS. I asked administrator to install xclip in HCP. But he said it would endanger to HPC. I am not root user. I am wondering whether there is a way to I can copy output of command line to clipboard directly without installing xclip. I do not want to use mouse to select and copy. Is there a way in terminal that it can redirect the output to clipboard?

Comment: Are you remotely connecting to the CentOS server through SSH?

Comment: If you're using puTTy on Windows, you can select the text and right click it, then it's copied to clip board. What SSH client are you using?

Comment: Do you have gcc? you could try recompiling it there. If not, you could statically compile it and send it via scp.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII. I am using the terminal in mac.

Comment: Command shift c might do it. Ctrl shift c works in terminal on ubuntu for me

Comment: Also, xclip won't work unless you forward X. You probably want to `<command> | tee output.file`, then pull the file via scp.

Comment: @xvan. I figure it out now. It is not as simple as my PC because it copy the the output from the remote and put it on local.

Comment: I might have a solution, but I need to test it first.

Answer (score 2):

This is sort of hackish:

Start a local xclip server:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do nc -l localhost 8888 | xclip
done
```

Connect with a reverse port redirection:

```
ssh <something something> -R 8888:localhost:8888
```

On the remote write what you want to copy to that port. Some options are:

```
echo "I WANT TO COPY THIS" | nc -C localhost 8888 #close on eof varies with version
```

Or

```
echo "I WANT TO COPY THIS" > /dev/tcp/localhost/8888
```

If both fail, you may still try with perl or python.

Comment: This is a good answer. Since you are already using port forwarding, run `nc -l localhost 8888` locally, so that others cannot connect to your system & copy their junk data on your clipboard.

Comment: @anishsane Could you edit my answer with your proposal? The only way I can think of protecting the remote port is connecting a remote server to a named pipe, the using forward port redirection on ssh to read that name pipe.

Comment: I am just saying that `nc -l 8888` in your answer should be replaced by `nc -l localhost 8888`, because the former is equivalent to `nc -l 0.0.0.0 8888` So any system on network can access it. Addition of `localhost` will imply that it can only be accessed from localhost (loopback interface).

Comment: However, there is _possibly_ one issue. (I have not yet tested): If you do `echo hi > /dev/tcp/localhost/8888; some_more_work; echo hello > /dev/tcp/localhost/8888` You would normally expect only `hello` on clipboard. but this will most likely copy everything till ssh session is active to clipboard. In this case, `hi\nhello`

Comment: Nc should close with eof, and restart, thats what the -c flag does.

Comment: OK... I thought that the connection to `nc -l` side will remain active till `ssh` is active...